# MySQL group_concat on groups listings

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have the following table:

```
id | group_id | str     | position_number
 1 |        1 | first   | 1
 2 |        1 | string  | 2
 3 |        2 | And     | 1
 4 |        2 | another | 2
 5 |        2 | string  | 3
```

I'm searching for the SQL query which returns the following result:

```
group_id | str
       1 | firststring
       2 | Andanotherstring
```

How can I do that with group concat, is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
group_id
, GROUP_CONCAT(str ORDER BY position_number SEPARATOR '')
FROM
your_table
GROUP BY group_id
```

Not so hard, isn't it?

It's a good idea to consult the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for such questions.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c30410/1/0)